# Angular8: using different template for same component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a scenario in Angular where I need to use different HTML template for same component ts file, something like this

```
let templateUrl: string;
switch (environment.country) {
  case 'India':
    templateUrl = './comp1-in.component.html'
    break;
  case 'Brazil':
    templateUrl = './comp1-br.component.html'
    break;

  default:
    templateUrl = './comp1.component.html';
    break;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comp1',
  templateUrl: templateUrl,
  styleUrls: ['./comp1.component.scss']
})
```

But this does not work as expected and instead of using the template it just renders the template path in the view

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should create one base component with reusable logic for all components and then for each country different component which will extend base component.

Then in parent component insert proper template based on country:

```
<app-india *ngIf="env.country === Country.India"></app-india>
<app-brazil *ngIf="env.country === Country.Brazil"></app-brazil>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do with Switch case.You could achieve this using ng-template with ngIf on the same template.

if you want to have different templates, you can have a look at [`p3x-angular-compile`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p3x-angular-compile)